# Calculate the difference of hours in string variables in ts / angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 string variables that each express an hour.

I need to know how long the difference between them is.

`"8:00"`- start time, `"15:00"` - end time.
The output should be `7`

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Date class have four overloaded constructors.

More info [here](https://javascript.info/date)

We can use: `new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)`

```
Math.abs(new Date(0,0,0,8).getHours()- new Date(0,0,0,15).getHours())
```

Make sure to parse String to Integer before using in the function call